# Error using firebase storage xmlhttprequest, attempting to return value as img src

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, material-ui, firebase-storage

I'm attempting to use base64 as image src however it returns null every time, does anyone how to render the image? I know request works because the data is showing up fine in the console logs along with no error messages.

I also assume this is because the function renders the Card before the request is completed, but considering everything is inside a useEffect function I don't think this should matter...

If I'm asking this question wrong please let me know how to improve!

Xmlhttprequest function (works fine):

```
                    const imgArray = []
                    getDownloadURL(officialRef).then((url) => {
                        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.responseType = 'text';
                        xhr.onload = (event) => {
                            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                                const instance = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)[0].base64
                                imgArray.push(instance)
                                console.log(imgArray[0])
                            }
                        };
                        xhr.open('GET', url);
                        xhr.send();
                        
                    }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
```

MUI CardMedia component (also tried: `${imgArray[0]}`):

```
                                    <CardMedia
                                        component="img"
                                        height="110"
                                        image={imgArray[0]}
                                        alt='Tech Club'
                                        />
```

Full Code:

```
                querySnapshot1.docs.map((item) => {
                    const officialRef = ref(storage, JSON.stringify(item.data().productID, null, 2));

                    const imgArray = []
                    getDownloadURL(officialRef).then((url) => {
                        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr.responseType = 'text';
                        xhr.onload = (event) => {
                            if(xhr.status === 200) {
                                const instance = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)[0].base64
                                imgArray.push(instance)
                                console.log(imgArray[0])
                            }
                        };
                        xhr.open('GET', url);
                        xhr.send();
                        
                    }).catch((error) => console.log(error))


                    return(
                            <Card sx={{ width: 220, marginLeft: 1,marginRight: 1,paddingTop: '.5em', border: '5px solid transparent',borderRadius: '10px', background: 'linear-gradient(#fff 0 0) padding-box, linear-gradient(to right, #0bd3d3, #f890e7)' }} >
                                <Link to={`products/${item.data().productID}`} style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
                                <CardActionArea>
                                    <CardMedia
                                        component="img"
                                        height="110"
                                        image={`${imgArray[0]}`}
                                        alt='Tech Club'
                                        />
                                    <CardContent>
                                        <Typography style={{color: '#000000'}} gutterBottom variant="h6" component="div">
                                            {item.data().title}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography style={{color: '#000000'}} gutterBottom variant="h7" component="div">
                                            {item.data().brand}
                                        </Typography>
                                        <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
                                            {item.data().category}
                                        </Typography>
                                    </CardContent>
                                </CardActionArea>
                            <CardActions>
                                    <Button size="small" variant='contained' sx={{background: '#f890e7',opacity: .85,border: '3px solid #0bd3d3', color: 'ivory', textDecoration: 'none', fontWeight: '1000', fontSize: '1.1em' }}>
                                        ${item.data().price}
                                    </Button>
                            </CardActions>
                            </Link>
                        </Card>
                        
                )})
```

Comment: I also console logged `typeof imgArray[0]` and it was indeed a string

Comment: Images for the same storage file render perfectly on other page after setting a useState[] so it must be an issue with mapping through multiple docs...